# Call setBackground twice on a text-view with same drawable id. What happens?

Tags: android, performance, view, android-view

I have a text-view and a drawable.
If I set the background of the textview using the same drawable id twice (for no specific reason), I was wondering if it would cause any performance loss.

I know that android goes through the whole measure-layout-draw pass for each view (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html), each time we call any set methods on it, like setText, setBackground, etc.

I want to know, in case, I accidentally call setBackground twice, using the same drawable, will android go through the whole drawaing cycle twice, causing a performance loss, or is this optimized by android, like maybe android remembers that I am setting the same background as previously set, so no need to go through the drawing cycle ?

If anybody has knowledge in this area, please help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in the source code for the [`View`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/75ae89837615fa9cebd6cbb051213c025c48bcf6/core/java/android/view/View.java) class.

`setBackgroundResource()` implements this check:

```
if (resid != 0 && resid == mBackgroundResource) {
     return;
}
```

and `setBackgroundDrawable()` (called by `setBackground()`) checks the references and does nothing if they are pointing to the same Drawable

```
if (background == mBackground) {
     return;
}
```

Therefore, if you're using the same reference/same resource id when calling `setBackground()`, you should not incur performance penalties since Android will not redo the whole drawable setting process.